# Graphing complex numbers on Casio fx-9750 GII

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

I have a Casio fx-9750GII, I'm starting to get to grips with just how useful it can be. For those familiar with it you will be aware it can graph functions.

However I noticed when looking through the set up menu it has a complex mode which can be set to a+bi. So I enabled that option and entered 3+4i as a function, the calculator does not draw anything.

How do I graph complex numbers?

Comment: Um, in case you didn't know, 3+4$i$ is just a point on the Argand plane. It is not a function, so its graph will be a single point. So what exactly do you mean by graphing a number?

Comment: Is there a way of doing that? I was taught that 3+4i graphed was a line from the origin to the point 3+4i.

Comment: Ah, different definitions. I consider a number $z$ to be a point. A lot of people consider them to be rays. Anyway, I have no idea about the working of your calculator. We don't use calculators in our class.